# PERL. Кол-во знаков после запятой после деления

Tags: perl, округление

Нужно с помощью Perl (или другим способом) поделить число, и результат вывести с точностью до 10 знаков после запятой.
Например, если в Bash использовать команду:

```
echo "scale=10;6518772587507843661 / 203"| bc
```

результат: 32112180234028786.5073891625

Если через Perl:

```
$a=6518772587507843661/203;
printf ("%.10f\n",$a);
```

результат: 32112180234028788.0000000000

Как в Perl сделать результат такой же, как и через "bc", чтобы ответ был - 32112180234028786.5073891625?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы упираетесь в точность вещественных чисел в интерпретаторе. А bc умеет длинную арифметику. Но, как всегда, можно воспользоваться библиотеками.

```
use Math::BigFloat;
Math::BigFloat->precision(-10); # это точность

my $x = Math::BigFloat->new(6518772587507843661);
my $y = Math::BigFloat->new(203);

$a=$x/$y;
print("$a\n");
```

или воспользоваться библиотекой bignum

Comment: Спасибо. Именно то, что мне нужно.